# ERROR 1364: 1364: Field 'ssl_cipher' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, insert

```
ERROR 1364: 1364: Field 'ssl_cipher' doesn't have a default value .
```

**SQL Statement:**

```
INSERT INTO `samedaycrm4`.`users` (`Host`, `User`, `Password`) VALUES ('%', 'Bonnie', '*BB71B8925EED8E5387A872A38E566BFCB0F78071')
```

I am trying to determine the cause of the error ERROR 1364: 1364: Field 'ssl_cipher' doesn't have a default value..?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ssl_cipher` column in your table has been marked `non-null`, but your `INSERT` query isn't providing a value for it. MySQL will try to assign the default value in these circumstances, but your column hasn't been given one.

You need either to set a default value for `ssl_cipher`, or alter the table such that the `ssl_cipher` is not marked as `non-null`

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. The Password field is marked right now as NN for not null...

Comment: Read the error message: it's the `ssl_cipher` column that's causing the problem.

Comment: You can also use something like this: INSERT INTO user (Host,User,ssl_cipher,x509_issuer,x509_subject) VALUES ('localhost', 'myUser','','','');

Comment: You could also provide the solution along with the explanation.

Answer (score 9):

//This happens due to the internal structure of user table in mysql database (mysql.user) has many column of administrative privileges which accept 'N' or 'Y' value but not NULL Value. Not assigning these values in user addition syntax by INSERT method will provide null values to table and hence error 1364 occur.
//instead using GRANT syntax will give no administrative privileges to user
mysql>use mysql;

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, CREATE
       -> ON database.*  //for all tables in DATABASE database
       -> TO 'user'@'localhost'
       -> IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

//user will get created

Answer (score -2):

FYI check comment from "Sergei Golubchik" at https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14579

***[ It doesn't look like a bug to me.
INSERT INTO mysql.user is deprecated since 3.23 - one should use GRANT or CREATE USER to add new users.
As for the GRANT failing on Windows, it's a duplicate of the BUG#13989, which is "Not a bug" either. GRANT fails because on Windows, installer adds the following line to my.ini
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
which prevents GRANT from auto-creating users.]***

And finally the implementation for CREATE USER, you can find at -

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html

It should solve your problem, using "CREATE USER" approach.

Comment: Grant doesn't work if the grant permissions get messed up for the sql root and you have to use the skip-grant-tables to login.